# How to check the type of a variable from a file with ifstream?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have a stream in a file (which is opened by `ifstream`) with `double`s and some `string` but I don't know their positions. For example:

```
1 2 3 4 g 3 2 t 1 d
```

So I have to read a stream as the above one, but I don't know how to differentiate the type of the variable before reading.

How can I do that with `ifstream` and with no knowledge about the order of the variables?

Comment: see my answer and show us you code so we can help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure your numbers are integers, use the code below. If not, replace `int` in `vec` and  `temp`  by  `double`

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    std::ifstream file {"fileLocation"};
    while(file.peek() != EOF)
    {
        if (isdigit(file.peek())){
            int temp;
            file >> temp;
            vec.push_back(temp);
            file.seekg(file.tellg() + file.gcount());

        }

        else
            file.seekg(static_cast<int>(file.tellg()) + 1);
    }
    for(auto const & el : vec ) std::cout << el << " ";


}
```

Comment: hey man do not do this!!!! Your answer is good, but let them think a bit!!!!! people ask this kind of questions and when you give them code they will just copy your code and use it for their benefit. better tell the owner of the post to post the code he/she have written.

Answer (score 0):

You can `peek()` the next character in the stream, and if it is a digit or sign then read the next value as a `double`, otherwise read it as a `string`.

Otherwise, just read everything from the stream as a `string`, and then use `std::stod()` or `std::strtod()` to attempt to convert each `string` to a `double`, and check the conversions for failure.